# /proc and /sys contain contain files but no data

Tags: mount, directory

/proc and /sys contain files but no data. All the files are there but the values are set to zero.  For this reason I can't access `ls` from the user prompt but only from within root.  In other words `ls` outputs as

`1835009 drwxr-xr-x 18 [user] [user] 4.0K Dec  3 12:41 ./`

and this is true for all directories. How do I restore the files in both /proc and /sys? The problem is not the creation of /proc or /sys, but the restoration of the files within these directories.

Would restoration from the live cd be possible?

Comment: `/proc` and `/sys` are pseudo-filesystems which provide interfaces to kernel data structures, they're not "real" files. What is the actual issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: That is intended behavior for /proc/.  /sys/ itself has no files. only directories. Rebooting recreates /proc and /sys.  Please pay attention to your question: ask what the solution for a problem is and don't add your own ideas. /proc and /sys to me do not seem to be the issue.

Comment: @steeldriver tsk :D

Comment: @Rinzwind great minds think alike ... fools seldom differ ;)

Comment: What I am trying to solve is why there is no list when I use the `ls` command

Comment: in other words, why is `./` displaying instead of a list of files?

Comment: Please add the output of `type -a ls` to your question

Comment: `ls is aliased to ls --color=auto'`
`ls is /usr/bin/ls`
`ls is /bin/ls`

Comment: When I enter `type -a ls` from the $ line, I get `ls is aliased to ls -AFSdhilrt --color=always --group-directories-first|more'`
`ls is /usr/bin/ls`
`ls is /bin/ls`

Comment: So the issue is just that your ls alias includes `-d`, which tells ls not to list the directory's contents